# Constructing an array of arrays in Java, wrong order of dimensions?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

With `T` being a type, either a primitive or a class, an array of `T` is `T[]`. A variable is declared as `T[] a;` and constructed as `new T[n]`. With `T t` you can then do `a[i]=t` or `t=a[i]`.

My issue is with `T` being `int[]`. With `int[][] a` the `a[i]` refers to one of `int[]` arrays within `a` and `a[i][j]` to an element within the same `int[]` array, so the analogy is fine here.

But constructing the `a` should be, by the analogy above, `a = new int[][n];` (replacing `T` with `int[]`, at the moment not worried that `a[i]` are undefined or `null`, I can assign/construct them later).
This, however, produces the following error:

> Cannot specify an array dimension after an empty dimension

But `new int[n][]` doesn't produce an error.

Furthermore `a = new int[m][n];` is ok, and it seems obvious that it constructs the array `a`, as well as each of its elements, all of them being arrays with the same length. But according to the analogy, the length of `a` should be `n` and the length of each `a[i]` should be `m`. But the previous paragraph made me suspect it's the other way around so I tried `int[][] a = new int[3][7];` and displayed `a.length` and `a[0].length`, which confirmed my suspicion.

*So when you construct an array of arrays, why do the lengths have to be given in reverse order? Does that depend on Java implementation, or is this wrong order universal?*

I have checked http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077367/learn-java/array-of-arrays.html but it doesn't clarify it; it also contains errors (`String [][] saa = { { { "Help" } } };`).

Comment: You have to highlight code. Please see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: the first dimension is of size m and the 2nd of size n, why does it seem reverse to you??

Comment: @yurib Because you put the dimension in square brackets **after** the type of array's elements. Just like `String [7]` would mean an array of 7 `String` elements, `int[3] [7]` should mean array of 7 `int[3]` elements. Similar for `int[] [7]`.

Comment: @Joiner Thank you. I should have done my homework before posting it. I was actually going to look things up and edit my post but _parakmiakos_ has done it for me, so thank you, too. (I don't know why I need reputation to review suggested edit for **my own** post, though.)

Answer (score 0):

from the [java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html)

> An array type is written as the name of an element type followed by some number of empty pairs of square brackets []. The number of bracket pairs indicates the depth of array nesting.

since you read it left to right, you should treat the leftmost pair of brackets as the top level of nesting.
this means that `int[m][n]` is an `n` length integer array nested in an `m` length array and not the other way arround.

Comment: I understand your argument for the ordering of dimensions. But it doesn't make sense to me, looking at it mathematically. However, I am OK to accept that this is an exception to the rule:

To construct an array with e.g. 7 of something, you put [7] afterwards. Except, of course, if "something" is an array: 7 of `int[3]` you construct by _inserting_ [7]: `int[7][3]` rather than putting it afterwards.

Comment: You are looking at it from the wrong direction. The reasoning is rather like this:
You are constructing an array of 7 Arrays. Each of those Arrays has a sub array of 3 integers. Thus it is perfectly logical.

Comment: @CarstenHoffmann You are starting from outside. When you construct an array, you start from the inside. In case of `int[]`, you first you put the innermost type, `int`, and _then_ the brackets. With multi-dimension array, you start dimensions from the outermost. To make that consistent, the above array (7 triplets) should either start from inside: `int[3][7]` or from outsidel: `[7][3]int` (`int` is the innermost part, therefore at the end). Instead, the correct way in Java is a hybrid using **both directions**: `int[7][3]`. Am I the only one who sees it this way?

Comment: P.S. I am aware that changing that part of Java syntax now would mess up loads of pre-existing Java code and therefore it would makes no sense. Don't worry, I have accepted this part of Java syntax, though, unlike many people, I see it as an exception to the rules, an inconsistency, but a clearly defined one now.